# Переделка программы из HSSF* в XSSF*

Tags: java

По своей неопытности написал программу которая работает с загружаемом файле `.xls`, теперь хочу переделать её чтобы работала с `.xlsx`.
Если я правильно понял из гугла, то мне достаточно поменять все `HSSF*` на `XSSF*`, импортировав соответвенно что требуется.
Но вот проблема, сделав это, при импорте через кнопку файла `.xlsx` возникает такая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
    at sample.testtabtwo$2.actionPerformed(testtabtwo.java:189)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
```

Строка кода 189 такая:

```
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

А вот и сам кусок кода:

```
else {
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
                int index = -1;
                try {
                    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                } catch (IOException ex) {  
                Logger.getLogger(Charges.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                String[] strs = new String[workbook.getNumberOfSheets()];
                for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
                    strs[i] = workbook.getSheetName(i);
                }
```

Всё тоже самое только когда всё идёт через HSSF - работает, через XSSF - нет.
Есть идеи? Занимаюсь только месяц, так что больно не бейте за код:)

Comment: Ошибка `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap` означает, что в classpath нет зависимости [Apache Commons Collections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4).

Comment: К сожалению из-за отсутсвия достаточного опыта, мне это мало что даёт :) Получается что при HSS есть зависимость а при XSS её нет :Р